# Best way to store categories and product type in DB

Tags: database-design

I have three product types. It will be more later.
Also I have product categories. category can't have multiple product type. So, how should I keep the categories.

1.`id | parent_id | name`

I'll set the product types as the root categories.
For example:

```
Electronic > computer > laptop
```

Electronic's parent id will be 0 and next categories will linked due to that.

1. `id | parent_id | product_type | name`

I'll get the electronic from product_type and computer's parent_id will be 0.

which way is better?

Answer (score 2):

For categories:

```
ID | Name | Parent_ID
```

(Parent ID is for category tree)

For products:

```
ID | Category_ID | Name | Description | Other
```

Let's say the category tree is like

```
Computers [ID: 1 | Parent: 0]
 |-Laptops [ID: 2 | Parent: 1]
 |-Desktop [ID: 3 | Parent: 1]
 |-Printers [ID: 4 | Parent: 1]
 |  |-Brand #1 [ID: 5 | Parent: 4]
 |  |-Brand #2 [ID: 6 | Parent: 4]
 |-Other stuff [ID: 7 | Parent: 1]
```

Then, if you want to display all products from from, for example, `Printers`, just do a recursion getting all items from `Printers` category and its subcategories.

## TL;DR

The first way is better

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a nested set design rather than what you are currently using, an adjacency list design.

Though it does work, if you are running into performance issues, a single query on a nested set can produce A LOT more information about the category than from an adjacency list (which requires multiple database calls).

I have used [this article on hierarchical data in mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), in the past for many applications and it works very well.

**TL;DR:**

**Adjacency List**

- Pros: Easy to implement
- Cons: Requires recursive database calls in order to determine information such as depth, and position in the tree.

**Nested Set**

- Pros: Can produce most info that you would need about your data in a single query
- Cons: Harder to implement

Answer (score 0):

does your db looks like this?

table: product_type

```
id   | parent_id | name
-------------------------------
1    | null      | Electronics
------------------------------- 
2    | 1         | Computer
-------------------------------
3    | 2         | Laptop
-------------------------------
```

if so, why do you need a further table to get the result?
when you need a new category, just add a new parrent and its children.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you have three product types now and that product types can be increased later, you need a table for Product Types -

```
Product_type
------------
1> product_type_id - Primary Key

2> product_type_name
```

Now you have categories table which will be of hierarchical category data and have one to many relationship from product_type table.(as you said categories can not have multiple product types) So your table design will be like

```
Product_categories
------------------

1> product_cat_id - Primary key

2> product_type_desc 

3> parent_product_type_id (for hierarchical relationship)

4> product_type_id - foreign key to **Product_type** table.
```

You can elaborate any further requirement here, so that we can help you.

Thanks